# Probability doubt

Tags: distribution, probability

Im working on a problem that goes as  --
There is a an initially unordered set of numbers. and the goal is to sort it. the sorting should be done by shuffling the numbers until they fall into their correct places(Yeah, Bogosort'ish :)) The shuffling has one optimization that if after a shuffling, any elements towards the beginning or towards the end of the list fall in their correct places, these elements will be fixed and the remaining elements will be shuffled using the above same logic. The problem is to calculate the average number f shuffles required to sort an initially unordered set of numbers, say 6.
I know its a distribution sequence along the line of probability but am not able to completely zero in on it. Any suggestions/advise in the correct direction or approach would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Already in math.stackexchange : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/expected-number-of-shuffles-to-sort-the-cards/21273

Answer (score 1):

This can be calculated recursively.

- A list of length 0 requires on average 0 shuffles. f(0) = 0.
- A list of length 1 requires on average 0 shuffles. f(1) = 0.
- A list of length 2 after shuffling has a few possibilities:

  - It is already sorted (50% chance): 0 shuffles.
  - It is not already sorted (50% chance):

    - Shuffling sorts it: 1 shuffle.
    - Shuffling does not help, we need to try again: 1 + f(2) shuffles.

This cna be written as:

```
f(2) = ((1/2) * 0) + ((1/2) * (1/2) * 1) + ((1/2) * (1/2) * (1 + f(2)).
f(2) = 2/3
```

You can continue in this way to larger inputs by reducing them to the smaller inputs that you have already solved.